# What are these lines?

Tags: bug, review-queue

[image: lines]

This is kind of annoying, and these lines don't seem to serve any purpose. Why are they here?

- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: [Brave](https://brave.com)
- Resolution: 1366x768

Comment: Obviously a painting glitch of some kind in your browser.  You probably have your own reasons for not using it, but with my web dev hat on I have to ask "What does it look like in Chrome?"

Comment: @DavidW Brave _is_ Chrome, only with better security. They literally took the Chrome browser and made it more secure.

Comment: This was already reported on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313837/323179).

Comment: I see the screenshot and all I can think is, "Isn't he bothered by the second line from the right?"

Comment: @MrLister It appears I missed that one. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FIXED

Finally, the issue has been resolved. You can check out the [Review Queues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review) to see the perfect, unmarred box!